# Using cURL to save external files to my Server

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I have a website to show opensource movies and videos.

I have saved urls in mysql and linked both videos as well as the images to the content server.

But users are complaining of slow website as images are getting fetched from outside and most of time Internet Explorer is not even displaying the image.

I just learnt about cURL and would like to save images as well as videos to my own server and provide mirror to original website.

I got " curl -O ('') ; " syntax at many places to do the task but don't know how to use it inside my php script.

In short:
I already have my form for url saving in mysql. I wish it to also save save file to a directory on my webserver and save file path to another column in mysql.

Any sort of help is welcome.
Thanx in Advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$local_file = "/tmp/filename.flv";//This is the file where we save the information
$remote_file = "http://www.test.com/filename.flv"; //Here is the file we are downloading


$ch = curl_init();
$fp = fopen ($local_file, 'w+');
$ch = curl_init($remote_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

---

I've decided to **update** this answer almost **7** years later.
For those who have `copy()` enabled for remote hosts, you can simply use:

```
copy("http://www.test.com/filename.flv", "/some/local/path/filename.flv");
```

Comment: Thanx for the code it works perfectly (there is small error of missing ; at end of second line for anyone else reading the post).

Thank you for the code, it works perfectly on localhost. Going to test it on remote host now.

Can you also please help me with a small piece of code to add in my form. So that file path and name are generated( /tmp/filename.flv ) and path info is saved to mysql.

I can get $remote_file in form and save that info to mysql. But still have trouble generating the file name and saving path to mysql.

Thanx once more for answer.

Comment: I've fixed the missing semicolon on the 2nd line. To be honest I'm not sure about what you need, what do you mean by "Can you also please help me with a small piece of code to add in my form" ?

Comment: I need a complete sample page with form to put url info and it adding path info to database and saving the file too.

I know it is too much to ask for, but I look forward to your answer.

Comment: heavy files of 300mb+ not getting transferred

Comment: Try adding this code `set_time_limit(0);` at the top your php file.

Comment: Sorry for not doing that. I was not aware of it till now.

But setting time limit is also not helping nor I am able to generate any error

Comment: I can also try to increase the `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);`
to `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5000);` , see if this works.